# ifstream::read doesn't tell how many bytes it really reads?

Tags: c++, ifstream, readfile

I'm using `ifstream::read` to read a file,

```
ifstream ifs("a.txt");
char buf[1024];
ifs.read(buf, 1024);
```

But a.txt's size might be less than `1000 bytes`, so how am I supposed to know how many bytes have been read from `ifs`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can get the amount of characters extracted by the last operation with [`std::ifstream::gcount`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount):

```
ifstream ifs("a.txt");
char buf[1024];
ifs.read(buf, 1024);
size_t extracted = ifs.gcount();
```

or

```
ifstream ifs("a.txt");
char buf[1024];
size_t extracted = ifs.read(buf, 1024).gcount();
```

since [`read(...)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) returns `*this`.